# Updated drush, but status shows old version

Tags: 7, drush

I have a D7 site running in a Vagrant VM.

I was getting the following error when attempting to run `drush updb` from the site folder:

> Command updatedb needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need
>   to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this
>   command.
>
> The drush command 'updb' could not be executed.

I simply couldn't figure out why this won't run, so I thought I'd update drush. It was on 8.0.0-rc4.

I updated via composer on my local machine, and when I type `drush --version` it shows 8.1.12.

But, when I run `drush status` it still shows 8.0.0-rc4, and to top it off, I still cannot run `drush updb`

What is going on here?

I have tried running `drush --uri=mysite.local updb` but that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

In Vagrant, you need to SSH to the machine and run Drush from there.

Comment: I am doing this.